# Trigger hover on multiple elements

Tags: html, css, hover, overlay

```
#red, #blue {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;        
}
div:hover {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
#red {
    background-color: red;
}
#blue {
    background-color: blue;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
} 


<div id="red"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
```

Is it possible to trigger hover event on multiple elements under cursor without using javascript? How can I make both squares yellow in [this simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/x7cWq/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Pretty little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XxmLt/)

Well all these answers are just **SWELL** so I'm throwing mine in just for **kicks n giggles**.

Wrap them into a blanket.  Hover the blanket, you change both to yellow.

### HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#red, #blue {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#red {
    background-color: red;
}
#blue {
    background-color: blue;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}
#wrap:hover > div {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

Comment: What if the elements can not be wrapped in another div, e.g. if they are not siblings?

Comment: @Scholar not being siblings isn't exactly a problem for this specific use-case (see example: https://jsfiddle.net/rLms7tne). but CSS needs frame of reference and "previous sibling" or "parent" aren't selector options so if you're trying something not matching my example, it wont work.  maybe check latest/greatest CSS features for a different solution

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to be able to select preceding elements, you cannot do this with CSS alone. CSS cascades down the tree, not up the tree. You can do this with JS though.

http://jsfiddle.net/x7cWq/1/

```
$('div').hover(function() {
    $('div').addClass('yellow');
});

$('div').mouseleave(function() {
    $('div').removeClass('yellow');
});
```

With CSS:

```
div:hover, 
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

Comment: Wow, mine's the only answer that actually works, and I get a downvote. I'm telling the truth: CSS **cannot** select a preceding element. OP asked if it was possible without JS: the answer is **no**.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like

```
#red:hover {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}

#red:hover + #blue {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
#blue:hover + #red {
        background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/x7cWq/2/)

```
#red:hover + #blue // triggers hover for another element
```

Comment: I just answered similarly (I think you beat me by a hair), but I realized `#blue:hover + #red` won't work with the given markup, because blue doesn't come before red. Unfortunately, there's no pure-css fix for that.

Comment: @Faust You're right.  I too missed it, thanks for pointing my mistake.